# In-depth explanation of Magento's Store / Store View / Website layers?

Tags: php, magento

Could anybody point me towards a good technical explanation of Magento's Store Views/Websites system on a programming level?

I am considering a customization of the system, but am not yet sure which one of these levels to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no canonical resource on this.  The best way to think about these views are with the concept of scope.  Certain data in Magento is returned differently depending on which level (website, store, etc. you're on)

I'd start by getting a good understanding of [the Layout system](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates).  Basically, layouts are abstracted out into a tree of "Block" objects.  Most of these Blocks objects render a specific phtml template file.

The phtml template files are considered the store's theme.  You can point to a different group of templates depending on which store, store view or website is currently selected.

Step Two would be to get familiar with the [configuration](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration) [system](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial).   Magento takes certain actions based on the values set here, and the values can be set on a global, website, or store level.  The obvious example here is locale.

Finally, Magento's [EAV model system](http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1) allows even the models to have have values scoped at the global, website, or store level.

Answer (score 11):

First thing to read is the Magento Designer's guide : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide

Yep, "Designer" rather than "Developper" :)
But this is a great background to undestand how things do articulate. And, let's be honest... in Magento, "Designer" is really the same as "Developper" and sometime as "System engineer". One can't be a good Magento Designer if not a Developper (imo).

Now, the SO community of Magento is still shy because there are not loads of Magento experts yet I guess. Being not humble enough, I may think that, as a brand new SOer, I found I could help in a few areas. So feel free to ask and I'm sure when someone knows, someone answers. At last, please keep in mind that Magento is so powerful and featured that one can be expert in design integration but not in sales workflow management nor in back-office use for instance. Expertise may be very segmented.

Have fun !

Answer (score 9):

I struggled with these concepts as well, and information on the differences is scarce even on Magento's own site. After a decent bit of searching, [I found this webinar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/getting-the-most-of-multi-store-retailing-webinar-transcript/) which does a great job of explaining the concepts behind sites, stores, and store views. I suggest you watch the video, but here are my takeaways:

- global (installation), website, and store view are scopes, store is not a scope
- stores allow unified shopping cart and session (check out gap.com oldnavy.com for example)
- websites do not share cart or session by default
- create different websites in the case that you want to offer different shipping methods, pricing, payment gateways, promos, or base currency
- stores are collection of store views, store points at a root category, all views within store point at same root category, though individual products may be hidden within views
- store views change way pages are presented, not the structure of catalog
- websites, stores, and storeviews can ALL be configured on the same domain or different domains

Answer (score 7):

**Global | Website | Store | Store View**

One of Magento’s advanced features allows for management of multiple websites and stores within one installation, and we have an amazing system to support this:  GWS - aka “Global, Website, Store.”

**Global**: This refers to the entire installation.

**Website**: Websites are ‘parents’ of stores.  A website consists of one or more stores. Websites can be set up to share customer data, or not to share any data

**Store (or store view group)**: Stores are ‘children’ of websites.  Products and Categories are managed on the store level.  A root category is configured for each store view group, allowing multiple stores under the same website to have totally different catalog structures.

**Store View**: A store needs one or more store views to be browse-able in the front-end.  The catalog structure per store view will always be the same, it simply allows for multiple presentations of the data in the front.  90% of implementations will likely use store views to allow customers to switch between 2 or more languages.

Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work

[Video: Creating Multiple Online Storefronts, Part 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part1/)

[Video: Creating Multiple Online Storefronts, Part 2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part-2/)

Comment: Hi @Luis, you said that "Products and Categories are managed on the store level". so where exactly the code that handle this? Thank you.