# Magento - Differentiate Normal orders and orders created programatically

Tags: php, magento

I am able to create orders programmatically using my custom module.

I wish to add a flag to differentiate between various types of orders that can be created from admin/websites and orders created from my custom module.

I understand that admin and website orders can be differentiated by

```
if(!empty($order->getRemoteIp()){
  //place online
}
else{
  // place by admin
}
```

However, I still want to differentiate between orders manually placed from admin and orders placed from my custom module.

The following are some solutions I thought of

1) Adding a prefix to the order or order-increment id.

2) Creating a new store during creation of module and add all orders from my custom module using that store. However, I am not sure of what implications this might cause.

3) I am able to change the store name during order creation using

```
$order->setStoreName('customName');
```

But, this is not visible in the admin grid or order detail page. I'm guessing they fetch the information for "Purchased From" from the store id.

I am looking for, what could be the best solution from the above, or a better solution if any.

Note: My module is currently compatible with magento v1.4 and above. So I will need a solution that covers most versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an order attribute and set it when you create your order.

To create an order attribute you can do like this, in your module folder, in `sql/mymodule_setup/mysql4-upgrade-VNUMBER.php`:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup ();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup ( 'core_setup' );

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn ( 
    $installer->getTable ( 'sales_flat_order' ), 
    'my_attribute_code',  // this is where you set the attribute code
    'varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL' );

$setup->startSetup ();
$setup->addAttribute ( 
    'order', 
    'my_attribute_code',
    array (
        'type' => 'int', // or text or whatever
        'label' => 'My attribute Label' 
));
$installer->endSetup ();
```

Then when dealing with the order, simply use

```
$order->setMyAttributeCode($value);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am considering this. However, could you tell me the implications of creating a new store for this? Do you think its unnecessary? Why is because, it is easily displayed in the "purchased from" section in the order details page.

Comment: Maybe you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16953750/1398056 which sums up differences between websites, stores, store views. As I don't really know what you are trying to achieve this might help you decide. Although it seems to me (at first sight) that creating a whole new store only to flag some of the orders would be a little too much, but again I can't be sure and this post should help you decide. Cheers.